# How to change background/Foreground in an Extended Toolkit PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, background, propertygrid, foreground, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a Extended Wpf Toolkit propertyGrid:

```
<wpg:PropertyGrid x:Name="pg" Width="450" Height="300" Margin="10" ShowSearchBox="False"  Background="Transparent" >
```

and here is what it looks like:

[image]

So it's pretty clear that the background doesn't entails the rows which are therefore independent.

That said I have seen that by adding

```
<wpg:PropertyGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        </wpg:PropertyGrid.Resources>
```

I am able to change some of the lines (not all) but I need to do that programmatically through code-behind.

This is what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Styling the WPF PropertyGrid has an example at:

https://gist.github.com/Tide

Save the PropertyGrid.xaml to your project, and in App.xaml add

```
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="PropertyGrid.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

inside:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Probably the best approach is using a Theme as shown on the old CodePlex site:

https://wpfpropertygrid.codeplex.com